# How to divide Android Tablet Emulator(Phonegap) into Different columns(parts)

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

Iam trying to divide the Android Emulator into 3 portions(columns),which should be done when i clicked a button/Image.And Each cloumn displays separate information.Can Anyone Help me how to   get this.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and you'll have what you need.

Comment: Barak actually here iam using Phonegap for developing the  applications.Can u give me sample example.Thanking you.